# How can I print document correctly?

Tags: c#

I have faced a simple problem, I am having hope that someone could helps me on this.

I have a form and when it loads and the user presses the Print button, the process completes successfully and print well to pdf file.

**But If I first press the View Button and press the Print Button afterward, no pdf files is printed..**

I'm using PrintDocument and PrintPreviewControl to process data as follow :

First Button to preview Data on PrintPreviewControl

```
private void ViewBt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter = 1;
    lastindex = 0;

    PrintDocument Pages = new PrintDocument();
    Pages.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(Pages_PrintPage);
    printPreviewControl1.Document = Pages;
    printPreviewControl1.InvalidatePreview();
}
```

Second Button to Print Data

```
private void PrinBt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PagePrintSetup.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        PrintDocument Pages = new PrintDocument();
        Pages.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings = PagePrintSetup.PrinterSettings;
        Pages.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(Pages_PrintPage);
        Pages.Print();
    }
}
```

Print Page Code

```
int counter = 1;
int i;
int lastindex = 0;
private void Pages_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{

    for ( i= lastindex; i < t.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(t.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(), new Font("arial", 20), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 150, counter * 25);

        lastindex = (i + 1);
        counter++;

        if (i != 0 && i % 45 == 0)
            break;
    }
    if (i < t.Rows.Count)
    {
        counter = 1;
        e.HasMorePages = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug pages_PrintPage in case you first press preview and afterwards print button? What is `t` in Pages_PrintPage?

Comment: Pilgerstorfer Franz .. I thank you .. based in your post i get the solution .. :)

Comment: Just add the simple lines to restart paint code to Print the document ..

counter = 1;
lastindex = 0;

    private void PrinBt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PagePrintSetup.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           counter = 1;
           lastindex = 0;
    
            PrintDocument Pages = new PrintDocument();
            Pages.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings = PagePrintSetup.PrinterSettings;
            Pages.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(Pages_PrintPage);
            Pages.Print();
        }
    }

Comment: Just add in PrinBt_Click Event 
counter = 1;
lastindex = 0;

Comment: But i want to ask another question .. if i want to print just the current page or some pages .. what is the best solution ?

Comment: First I would Add your solution as answer to your question. Afterwards pls check the tags to your question (see @OndrejTucny ASP.Net??) And finally, please check SO for an answer for your new question - if there is non create a new question!) ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the simple lines to reuse paint event for printing the document ..

```
counter = 1;
lastindex = 0;

private void PrinBt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PagePrintSetup.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       counter = 1;
       lastindex = 0;

        PrintDocument Pages = new PrintDocument();
        Pages.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings = PagePrintSetup.PrinterSettings;
        Pages.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(Pages_PrintPage);
        Pages.Print();
    }
}
```